# How to use sscanf for strings with spaces?

Tags: c

for example I have string:

```
34912512        34912767        a.b.c.d.e - i.f.g.h.i       HJ      -
```

this code does not work:

```
sscanf (line, "%ld\t%ld\t%s\t%s\t%s", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e );
```

Answer (score 5):

This will read up until a newline:

```
char a[123];
sscanf(line, "%[^\n]", a);
```

If you also wanted it to read up until a tab, you can change it to: `"%[^\t\n]"`

Since it seems you've already read this string into the buffer `line`, an alternative to `sscanf` is `strtok`, which will return pointers to tokens of `line` (separated by spaces, tabs, whatever).

Answer (score 2):

`%s` matches a sequence of bytes that are not white-space characters. So it will stop on any whitespace.

Assuming your input is tab separated, this may work

`sscanf(line, "%ld\t%ld\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);`

But please limit number of characters that can be read with %[^\t] or there will be potential buffer overflow. Also check for return value of sscanf() to make sure it filled all the parameters before relying on them.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question and I want to add information :
if you want to seperate the data, exclude spaces tabs and minus characters you can do this:

```
sscanf(line,"%d %d %s %*s %s %s %*s",&a,&b,c,d,e);
```

The operator %*s means the string is read but ignored with no need for varaible.
The output for the string :

```
34912512        34912767        a.b.c.d.e - i.f.g.h.i       HJ      -
```

after sscanf is:

```
printf("%d %d %s %s %s\n",a,b,c,d,e);

34912512 34912767 a.b.c.d.e i.f.g.h.i HJ
```